# What's the difference between "Her eyes were running" and "She was crying"?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between:

> Her eyes were running.

And

> She was crying.

Comment: _Her eyes were running_ is not a common phrase, and if it was used it would not necessarily mean that she was crying: it might mean, for example, that her eyes were watering from cold.

Comment: Peeling onions can do this.

Comment: Noses run, eyes water; both could be a response to seasonal allergies, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Her eyes are running* because of something which is not related to her emotions or because of some pain (something is irritating her eyes).

*She is crying* because of some emotion, as for example, because of pain inflicted by someone or something, or because of joy